# Surrogate duality gap and feasibility in primal-dual interior point methods (Boyd)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I have been reading through Stephen Boyd's famous text book *Convex optimization* ([PDF](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)).

Regarding primal-dual interior point methods, §11.7.2 on page 612 states:

> In the primal-dual interior-point method the iterates $x(k)$, $\lambda(k)$, and $\nu(k)$ are not necessarily feasible, except in the limit as the algorithm converges.

Note: $x$ is the primal variable, $\lambda$ and $\nu$ are the dual variables (Lagrange multipliers associated with the inequality and equality constraints, respectively).

There are two things I do not understand about the statement above, which is quite central to the primal-dual interior point method (Algorithm 11.2).

**First,** how can the iterate $\nu(k)$ possibly be infeasible? The feasibility set of the dual variable $\nu$ is $\mathbb R^p$ (page 561), so *any* $\nu$ should be feasible. What am I missing?

**Second,** the initialization of the primal-dual interior-point method (Algorithm 11.2) is  primal-feasible and dual-feasible (regarding $x$ and $\lambda$). Step 3 of the Algorithm (line search) guarantees that the next iterate will also be feasible (regarding $x$ and $\lambda$). Doesn't this imply that the iterates $x(k)$, $\lambda(k)$, and $\nu(k)$ are *necessarily feasible?*

Finally, why is the surrogate gap then required after all?

Comment: Regarding your first question on infeasibility. Infeasibility should be understood as the triple $(x(k),\lambda(k),\nu(k))$ not satisfying both the equality constraint $Ax=b$ and the inequality constraints $f_{i}(x)\leq 0$. In my experience the equality constraint is not required to be satisfied at each iterations of the interior point method.